# Intrisic store - bad performance

Tags: c++, intrinsics, xeon-phi

I want to write benchmark for Xeon Phi (60 core). In my program i use the OpenMP standard and Intel intrinsics. I implemented parallel version of algorithm (5-point stencil computation) which is faster under 230 times than scalar algorithm. I want add SIMD to parallel code. I have problem with performance. When i call _m512_store_pd() performance of computations is reduced and parallel version with SIMD is slower than version without SIMD. What is the problem? What should I do to get better performance?

```
for(int i=start; i<stop; i+=threadsPerCore)
        {
            for(int j=8; j<n+8; j+=8)
            {
               __m512d v_c = _mm512_load_pd(&matrixIn[i * n_real + j]);
               __m512d v_g = _mm512_load_pd(&matrixIn[(i - 1) * n_real + j]);
               __m512d v_d = _mm512_load_pd(&matrixIn[(i + 1) * n_real + j]);
               __m512d v_l = _mm512_loadu_pd(&matrixIn[i * n_real + (j - 1)]);
               __m512d v_p = _mm512_loadu_pd(&matrixIn[i * n_real + (j + 1)]);

               __m512d v_max = _mm512_max_pd(v_c, v_g);
               v_max = _mm512_max_pd(v_max, v_d);
               v_max = _mm512_max_pd(v_max, v_l);
               v_max = _mm512_max_pd(v_max, v_p);

              _mm512_store_pd(&matrixOut[i * n_real + j], v_max);
            }
}
```

I start computation from 8 becouse i have one vector at the beginning and one vector at the end are halo elements. n_real is size of vector -> n + 16. start and stop are computed, becouse i partition matrix for 60 cores and opne part (m/60) is computed by 4 HM threads.

Comment: Can you not organise your data such that the data is algined for the result? I'm not sure how it is these days, but it used to be terrible to use unaligned stores for streaming data.  Other than that, not sure what o suggest. Have you looked at what code the compiler generates in the first place? Both gcc and clang tend to generate pretty decent SIMD code wheneve the compiler understands enough of what is going on and how to translate it - and that doesn't look very complicated.

Comment: It's mistake. I don't use "storeu" intrinsic for write data to memory. Both matrixes matrixIn and matrixOut are aligned to 64bytes. Use "storeu" it had to be a mistake when i copyed code. I'm sorry. I compile program with: icc -mmic -O3 -openmp

Comment: Well, I don't have a machine with the right instruction set, nor do I have icc (and I used to work for AMD, and still don't buy Intel CPU's for my own machine for a number of reasons - and my current machine is the backup with an even older processor, because my other machine is a tad b0rked). I would still check what code the compiler actually produces - it entirely possible that your intrinsics are almost identical to what the compiler already did, hence "no difference" - I've seen that more than once with gcc and clang, and icc is supposed to be pretty good.

Comment: Tommorow I compile the program with the flag generating asembly code and I will see how it works and how my compiler translate this intrisic. Mayby it will be resolve for my problem.

Comment: I compiled code and i saw asembly file. Intrisic are translate in good way. But I still don't know what is the problem.

Comment: That's not what I was saying - I tried to say that the compiler may indeed generate same or similar code WITHOUT intrinsics, and that means you don't see any/much difference.

Answer (score 0):

Someone (maybe you) seems to have asked an identical question (at least, the code sample quoted is the same as yours) on Intel Developer Zone at https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/topic/531721 where there are answers (including a rewrite that got 40% performance improvement).

Perhaps reading that would be useful?

(If it was you, I see no objection to asking in both places, but it would be polite to tell people here that you have already asked there, so that they don't waste time reproducing answers that people have already given in the other forum).